# URL amigável com .htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Gostaria de uma ajuda de vocês pois já tentei algumas vezes mas não cheguei no resultado esperado. Preciso através do htaccess, fazer o seguinte procedimento: trocar a url que é mostrada no browser, exemplo:

URL atual:

```
meusite.com.br/criacao_de_sites_e_lojas_virtuais.php
```

URL nova:

```
meusite.com.br/criacao-sites
```

Comment: isso te ajuda? http://blog.thiagobelem.net/aprendendo-urls-amigaveis/

Comment: Rodrigo, tentei usar os métodos do Thiago mas não consigo aplicá-los totalmente. Olha o link: visoart.com ... preciso embelezar estes links. Tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Deve ter umas 3 ou 4 respostas pra isso no site já (nao sei se alguma te serve, mas tem bons exemplos).

Comment: @marcosvinicius a melhor forma que conheço é a do thiago belem, é a mais simples e eficiente, qual o problema que te ocorre? você leu tudo que ele escreveu?

Answer (score 4):

O htaccess não vai mudar a sua URL, ela permanecerá a mesma.
É o contrário do que você escreveu, o utilizador vai escrever:

```
meusite.com.br/criacao-sites
```

O htaccess é um arquivo de orientação/leitura.
A sua URL permanecerá a mesma e o htaccess irá interpretá-la conforme as regras e orientar o acesso a um determinado directório/recurso.

Utilize o RewriteRule para escrever uma regra específica para a URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^criacao-sites criacao_de_sites_e_lojas_virtuais.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

O exemplo que você citou nos comentários abaixo:

```
http://visoart.com/portal/php/visoart_empresa_web_design_design_grafico_porto_alegre.php
```

Ficaria assim:

```
#ativamos a reescrita
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#quando o utilizador escrever no browser .../portoalegre, o htaccess executa um redireccionamento interno para o arquivo "visoart_empresa_web_design_design_grafico_porto_alegre.php" dentro do directório "/portal/php/".
RewriteRule ^portoalegre portal/php/visoart_empresa_web_design_design_grafico_porto_alegre.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

Com a alteração acima, bastava escrever no browser a seguinte URL:

```
http://visoart.com/portoalegre
```

Comment: Como poderia reescrever estas url's ridículas que o browser chama assim que acionamos o link?

vide http://visoart.com

Comment: @marcosvinicius é exatamente a mesma forma como escrevi acima, veja, alterei a resposta para você ver o resultado.

Answer (score 4):

Tenta algo assim

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^criacao-sites(.*)$ criacao_de_sites_e_lojas_virtuais.php
```

Answer (score 3):

Redirecione todas as requisições para um script de entrada da sua aplicação.
Nesse script de entrada (index.php no exemplo abaixo) interprete a URL incluindo a página apropriada (isso permite a você fazer controle de acesso e erros de sua aplicação).

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on

# Nao aplica o redirecionamento caso 
# o que esteja sendo acessado seja um arquivo ou pasta.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Redireciona para o arquivo index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

**index.php**

```
// Remove da URL a pasta da aplicacao,
// deixando apenas os parametros.
$aux = str_replace('index.php', '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$parameters = str_replace($aux, '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

// Recupera as partes da URL.
// Se você acessar http://meusite.com.br/criacao-sites
// $urlParts será:
//      array('criacao-sites')
//
// Se você acessar http://meusite.com.br/criacao-sites/blogs
// $urlParts será:
//      array('criacao-sites', 'blogs')
$urlParts = explode('/', $parameters);

// Com base nas partes redirecione como desejar.
if ($urlParts[0]=='criacao-sites')
    require_once 'criacao-sites.php';
else if ($urlParts[0]=='contato')
    require_once 'contato.php';
else
    require_once 'erro-404.php';
```

Você pode criar um array de mapeamento para facilitar (ao invés dos IFs demonstrados no exemplo apenas para efeito didático) ou até mesmo consultar o banco de dados para saber para que arquivo a URL deve ser mapeada (o que permite a você criar um sistema de tradução de URLs!).

Aconselho usar um framework que já encapsule isso pra você. Uma boa opção é o Yii: http://www.yiiframework.com/ .

Answer (score 3):

#### A forma mais fácil e prática é essa:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On

        RewriteRule ^criacao-sites/?$ /criacao_de_sites_e_lojas_virtuais.php [NC,L]
        # Você pode adicionar quantas URLs quizer. Ex:
        RewriteRule ^nova-url-amigavel/?$ /nome-do-arquivo-que-ira-abir.php [NC,L]

    </IfModule>
```

Eu só utilizo dessa forma. Muito bom!

Answer (score 2):

Não sei você entendeu bem como funciona url amigável, então vou tentar explicar.
O `htaccess` não irá reescrever sua url no browser de `criacao-sites criacao_de_sites_e_lojas_virtuais.php` para `criacao-sites`, o que você precisa fazer é, reescrever seu código `html`, veja:

Em seu site, onde o código é:

```
<a href="criacao_de_sites_e_lojas_virtuais.php" title="Criação de sites">Criação</a>
```

Altere para:

```
<a href="criacao-sites" title="Criação de sites">Criação</a>
```

Então utiliza a solução proposta pelo @Filipe em seu `htaccess`, para quando o browser chamar a url "http://visoart.com/portal/php/criacao-sites", o `htaccess` reescreva para o caminho correto em seu arquivo original `criacao_de_sites_e_lojas_virtuais.php`